# Trying to copy TD element formSharePoint and getting weird error

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my non-working code:

```
        SnapShotDate = SnapShot & M
        'Wait for site to fully load

        URL = SnapShotDate

        'Wait for site to fully load
        IE.Navigate2 URL
        Do While IE.Busy = True
           DoEvents
        Loop

        With ActiveSheet.Name
            x = IE.document.body.innertext
            StartDate = InStr(1, x, "In-Market Start Date ")
            EndDate = InStr(1, x, "In-Market End Date ")
            ActualDate = Mid(x, StartDate + 10, EndDate - StartDate - 10)
                .Range(y, 35) = ActualDate
        End With
```

I'm concatenating two variables together to come up with the URL; this works fine.  I'm searching the URL for a date, which is between 'In-Market Start Date' and 'In-Market End Date'.  I can find the value, and fit it into the string named 'ActualDate'.  Now, when I try to write it into a cell, I get this error: 'run-time error 424 object required'

This line always throws an error.
.Range(y, 35) = ActualDate

I'm not sure what's wrong here.  Also, I'm thinking there may be a better approach, since this seems kind of difficult, and I've learned, over time, if something seems difficult in Excel, it's probably because you are doing it wrong.  Can someone here give me a little guidance on what is wrong here?  Also, can I possibly do this in a more efficient fashion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.Name` from `With ActiveSheet.Name` as it's not needed.

Also,  change the `.Range(y, 35)` to `.Cells(y, 35)`.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was a mistake.  i got there because without that, I get this error: 'run-time error 1004' application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't spot the incorrect use of `.Range`. Answer amended.